# Changing the width of the character output with tkinter in Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am outputting a list of data in various labels inside my `tkinter` window. My problem is that I want to space out the data in columns but when outputting the data, it is skewed and out of place, even when using `ljust`. It appears that the characters are all different in size therefore `ljust` doesn't work.

I'm wondering if there is any way to change the actual width of the characters so that they can all be the same size, maybe if there is a font with equal sized characters that anybody knows about ?

Comment: Maybe this can help you? It's about min / max - width / height.
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/4399545/12488560](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4399545/12488560)

Comment: Does this answer your question: [pretty-print-data-in-tkinter-label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58658656/pretty-print-data-in-tkinter-label)

Answer (score 0):

This will output the names of the fonts for your system:

```
import sys
from   Tkinter import Tk
import tkFont
root = Tk()
fnames = list(tkFont.families())
fnames = sorted(fnames)
k = 0
for s in fnames:
    k=k+1
    sys.stdout.write(str(k)+'\t'+s+'\n')
```